# Keep getting NS record query failed: NXDOMAIN on Kali Linux dnsenum commands

Tags: command-line, kali-linux, dns

- the URL does not matter seeing as I have changed it to different websites multiple times
- I am new to Kali and Linux in general

```
┌──(admin㉿LAPTOP-JCHDG93R)-[~]
└─$ dnsenum --noreverse -o mydomain.xml https://www.example.com/
dnsenum VERSION:1.2.6

-----   https://www.example.com/   -----


Host's addresses:
__________________



Name Servers:
______________

 https://www.example.com/ NS record query failed: NXDOMAIN

┌──(admin㉿LAPTOP-JCHDG93R)-[~]
└─$
```

Screenshots from the command line:
[image]

Any search results I got from NXDOMAIN was that the URL did not exist even though they do.

Comment: "I am new to Kali and Linux in general" - computers in general by the look of your question - https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Answer (score 1):

The Kali Linux tool `dnsenum` takes a domain name as an operand, as shown in [the Kali Linux documentation for the tool](https://www.kali.org/tools/dnsenum/):

```bash
dnsenum --noreverse -o mydomain.xml example.com
```

In your question, you appear to give the utility a URL rather than a domain name.  This prompts the utility to respond with a DNS name server error since it can't find the given domain (since it's a URL, not a domain name).  The error "NXDOMAIN" means "non-existent domain".

In short, remove the leading `https://` and the trailing `/` from the final argument on the command line.